# How to run two functions in mocha test sequentially

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I have two describe blocks in my mocha-chai test, one for testing a POST API and another for a GET API. There is a dependency like the function for the GET API in turn calls the function for the POST API at first.

However, when I call both the functions one after another, both of them start simultaneously and thus failing.

The code looks like below :

```
 var server;
 var mongodb;

  before(function (done) {
    server = require('../../../app.js'); // same as "node app.js"
    done();
  })

  after(function (done) {
    server.close();
  })

function this_is_post_call() {
    describe('POST call', ()=> {
        it('Creating project', (done) => {
            chai.request(server)
            .post('/create/myproject')
            .send()
            .end((err, res) => {
             expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);

          done();
        });
    });

});
}

function this_is_get_call() {
    this_is_post_call();
    describe('GET call', ()=> {
        it('Reading project', (done) => {
            chai.request(server)
            .get('/read/myproject')
            .send()
            .end((err, res) => {
            expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);

         done();
        });
    });

}

this_is_post_call();
this_is_get_call();
```

Basically when I run this the standalone this_is_post_call() and the one inside this_is_get_call() , gets called simultaneously and it is failing as it tries to create same project twice.

What is the efficient way to call them sequentially so that they don't start until the previous one finishes.

Thanks.

Comment: wrap both calls inside a describe block.

Answer (score 0):

something like this might work (not completely sure about the chai.request part)

```
var server;
var mongodb;

describe('server', () => {
  before(function (done) {
    server = require('../../../app.js'); // same as "node app.js"
    done();
  })

  after(function (done) {
    server.close();
  })

  beforeEach(() => {
    // find a way to clear the database
    // using mongodb variable maybe
  })

  describe('when you make a post', () => {
    var postResult
    beforeEach((done) => {
      chai.request(server)
          .post('/create/myproject')
          .send()
          .end((err, res) => {
            var postResult = res
            done();
          });
    })


  })

  it('should respond with OK', () => {
    expect(postResult.statusCode).to.equal(200);
  })

  it('should let you make make a get', () => {
    chai.request(server)
        .get('/read/myproject')
        .end((err, res) => {
          expect(err).to.be.null;
          expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);
          done();
        });
  })
})
```

something like this might work too if you don't have a way to clear the database

```
var server;
var mongodb;

describe('server', () => {
  before(function (done) {
    server = require('../../../app.js'); // same as "node app.js"
    done();
  })

  after(function (done) {
    server.close();
  })

  it('should let you post and then get', () => {
    var postResult
    beforeEach((done) => {
      chai.request(server)
          .post('/create/myproject')
          .send()
          .end((err, res) => {
            expect(postResult.statusCode).to.equal(200);
            chai.request(server) // not sure if this is the correct chai.request format
                .get('/read/myproject')
                .end((err, res) => {
                  expect(err).to.be.null;
                  expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);
                  done();
                });
          });
    })
  })
})
```